# Use assign from plug to view (elixir / phoenix)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I have my api pipeline in which I want to add a plug which basically does some operations in the database and based on the response it does an assign which I then use on my view.

I´m having problems with passing the assign from the plug to the view.

**web/router.ex**

```
pipeline :api do
  plug ApiV2.Plug.Authenticate, repo: Auth.Repo
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
end
```

**web/controllers/auth.ex** (just the assign)

```
defmodule ApiV2.Plug.Authenticate do
     @behaviour Plug
     import Plug.Conn
     import Phoenix.Controller

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    assign(conn, :current_user, 'user')
  end

end
```

**web/controllers/address_controller.ex**

```
defmodule ApiV2.AddressController do
  use ApiV2.Web, :controller

  alias ApiV2.Address

  def index(conn, params) do
    json conn, @current_user
  end
end
```

I´ve got to the point where it tries to return :current_user ( I suppose), but, as the assign is wrong, it only returns

```
null
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values set using `assign` are available in the `conn.assigns` map. `@current_user` is a module attribute which returns `nil` since it's not set in this module.

This should work:

```
json conn, conn.assigns.current_user
```